# regex find and replace 'input tags'

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, find

I'm quite new to regular expression which I have trial and error test.

How can I replace:

```
<input name="token" type="text" id="test" value="">
```

like it will first search for the `id="test"` if the *id* exist it will set a 'variable' in `value=""` tags.

but if `value=""` has containing a varianble

ex:

```
<input name="token" type="text" id="test" value="token" />
```

it should replace the whole `value="token"` into a a desired variable.

`preg_match('%<[^>]*(id="test"[^>]*>)([^<]*)</[^>]*>%', $html, $match);`

which is it only search for HTML tags which has closing tags

ex: `<div id="test"></div>`

and for the value from 'input tags'. I came up with this solution which is not good.

`$data['token'] = 'test';`

`str_replace(array_keys($data),array_values($data),$html);`

can someone help me and give me some tips on regular expression on PHP. thank you.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for this, use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: yes I know but I just want to try. Like I stated I want to try trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<[^>]*value="(['token'"]*)"[^>]*>


Negated char class [^>] 0 to infinite times 
[greedy] matches any character except:> The character >
value=" Literal value="
1st Capturing group (['token'"]*)
Char class ['token'"] 0 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
'token'" One of the following characters 'token'"
```